# What are linux irq domains, why are they needed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt

What are irq domains, i read kernel documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt) they say:

> The number of interrupt controllers registered as unique irqchips
>   show a rising tendency: for example subdrivers of different kinds
>   such as GPIO controllers avoid reimplementing identical callback
>   mechanisms as the IRQ core system by modeling their interrupt
>   handlers as irqchips, i.e. in effect cascading interrupt controllers.

How GPIO controller can be called as interrupt controller?

Answer (score 40):

> What are linux irq domains, why are they needed?

It's documented perfectly in the first paragraph of [Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt), so I will assume that you already know it. If no -- please ask what is unclear regarding that documentation. The text below explains how to use IRQ domain API and how it works.

> How GPIO controller can be called as interrupt controller?

Let me answer this question using [max732x.c](/questions/tagged/max732x.c) driver as a reference ([driver code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3.1/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-max732x.c)). It's a GPIO driver and it also acts like interrupt controller, so it should be a good example of how IRQ domain API works.

### Physical level

To completely understand further explanation, let's first look into MAX732x mechanics. Application circuit from [datasheet](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX7325.html) (simplified for our example):

[image: MAX7325 Typical Application Circuit]

When there is a change of voltage level on P0-P7 pins, MAX7325 will generate interrupt on INT pin. The driver (running on SoC) can read the status of P0-P7 pins via I2C (SCL/SDA pins) and generate separate interrupts for each of P0-P7 pins. This is why this driver acts as **interrupt controller**.

Consider next configuration:

[image: interrupt cascading]

"Some device" changes level on P4 pin, tempting MAX7325 to generate interrupt. Interrupt from MAX7325 is connected to GPIO4 IP-core (inside of SoC), and it uses line #29 of that GPIO4 module to notify CPU about interrupt. So we can say that MAX7325 is **cascaded** to GPIO4 controller. GPIO4 also acts as interrupt controller, and it's cascaded to GIC interrupt controller.

### Device tree

Let's declare above configuration in device tree. We can use bindings from [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-max732x.txt) as reference:

```
expander: max7325@6d {
    compatible = "maxim,max7325";
    reg = <0x6d>;

    gpio-controller;
    #gpio-cells = <2>;

    interrupt-controller;
    #interrupt-cells = <2>;

    interrupt-parent = <&gpio4>;
    interrupts = <29 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
};
```

The meaning of properties is as follows:

- `interrupt-controller` property defines that device generates interrupts; it will be needed further to use this node as `interrupt-parent` in "Some device" node.
- `#interrupt-cells` defines format of `interrupts` property; in our case it's `2`: 1 cell for line number and 1 cell for interrupt type
- `interrupt-parent` and `interrupts` properties are describing interrupt line connection

Let's say we have driver for MAX7325 and driver for "Some device". Both are running in CPU, of course. In "Some device" driver we want to request interrupt for event when "Some device" changes level on P4 pin of MAX7325. Let's first declare this in device tree:

```
some_device: some_device@1c {
    reg = <0x1c>;
    interrupt-parent = <&expander>;
    interrupts = <4 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING>;
};
```

### Interrupt propagation

Now we can do something like this (in "Some device" driver):

```c
devm_request_threaded_irq(core->dev, core->gpio_irq, NULL,
        some_device_isr, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_ONESHOT,
        dev_name(core->dev), core);
```

And `some_device_isr()` will be called each time when level on P4 pin of MAX7325 goes from low to high (rising edge). How it works? From left to the right, if you look to the picture above:

- "Some device" changes level on P4 of MAX7325
- MAX7325 changes level on its INT pin
- GPIO4 module is configured to catch such a change, so it's generates interrupt to GIC
- GIC notifies CPU

All those actions are happening on hardware level. Let's see what's happening on software level. It actually goes backwards (from right to the left on the picture):

- CPU now is in interrupt context in GIC interrupt handler. From [gic_handle_irq()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c#L315) it calls `handle_domain_irq()`, which in turn calls `generic_handle_irq()`. See [Documentation/gpio/driver.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/driver.txt) for details. Now we are in SoC's GPIO controller IRQ handler.
- SoC's GPIO driver also calls `generic_handle_irq()` to run handler, which is set for each particular pin. See for example how it's done in [omap_gpio_irq_handler()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-omap.c#L703). Now we are in MAX7325 IRQ handler.
- MAX7325 IRQ handler ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-max732x.c#L481)) calls `handle_nested_irq()`, so that all IRQ handlers of devices connected to MAX7325 ("Some device" IRQ handler, in our case) will be called in `max732x_irq_handler()` thread
- finally, IRQ handler of "Some device" driver is called

### IRQ domain API

GIC driver, GPIO driver and MAX7325 driver -- they all are using IRQ domain API to represent those drivers as interrupt controllers. Let's take a look how it's done in MAX732x driver. It was added in [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=479f8a5744d8141e95ef40ab364ae2d3648848ef) commit. It's easy to figure out how it works just by reading IRQ domain documentation and looking to this commit. The most interesting part of that commit is this line (in `max732x_irq_handler()`):

```c
handle_nested_irq(irq_find_mapping(chip->gpio_chip.irqdomain, level));
```

`irq_find_mapping()` will find linux IRQ number by hardware IRQ number (using IRQ domain **mapping** function). Then `handle_nested_irq()` function will be called, which will run IRQ handler of "Some device" driver.

### GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP

Since many GPIO drivers are using IRQ domain in the same way, it was decided to extract that code to GPIOLIB framework, more specifically to GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP. From `Documentation/gpio/driver.txt`:

> To help out in handling the set-up and management of GPIO irqchips and the
> associated irqdomain and resource allocation callbacks, the gpiolib has
> some helpers that can be enabled by selecting the `GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP` Kconfig
> symbol:

> - `gpiochip_irqchip_add()`: adds an irqchip to a gpiochip. It will pass
>   the `struct gpio_chip*` for the chip to all IRQ callbacks, so the callbacks
>   need to embed the `gpio_chip` in its state container and obtain a pointer
>   to the container using `container_of()`.
>   (See `Documentation/driver-model/design-patterns.txt`)

> - `gpiochip_set_chained_irqchip()`: sets up a chained irq handler for a
>   `gpio_chip` from a parent IRQ and passes the `struct gpio_chip*` as handler
>   data. (Notice handler data, since the irqchip data is likely used by the
>   parent irqchip!) This is for the chained type of chip. This is also used
>   to set up a nested irqchip if `NULL` is passed as handler.

[This](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=984f66432e357701194abc7f753dcad89a1f9de3) commit converts IRQ domain API to GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP API in MAX732x driver.

### Next questions

Further discussion is here:

- [part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377846/what-is-chained-irq-in-linux-when-are-they-need-to-used)
- [part 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391340/when-we-use-irq-set-chained-handler-the-irq-line-will-be-disabled-or-not/34426034#34426034)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comment I found in *include/linux/irqdomain.h*:

> Interrupt controller "domain" data structure. This could be defined as
>   a irq domain controller. That is, it handles the mapping between
>   hardware and virtual interrupt numbers for a given interrupt domain.

the actual structure I think it's referring to there is irq_domain.