# what is chained irq in linux, when are they need to used?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, interrupt-handling, irq

What is chained IRQ ? What does `chained_irq_enter` and `chained_irq_exit` do, because after an interrupt is arised the IRQ line is disabled, but `chained_irq_enter` is calling functions related to masking interrupts. If the line is already disabled why to mask the interrupt ?

Comment: It's continuation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371352/what-are-linux-irq-domains-why-are-they-needed) question.

Comment: Next part is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391340/when-we-use-irq-set-chained-handler-the-irq-line-will-be-disabled-or-not/34426034#34426034).

Answer (score 11):

> what is chained irq ?

There are two approaches how to call interrupt handlers for child devices in IRQ handler of parent (interrupt controller) device.

1. Chained interrupts:

   - "chained" means that those interrupts are just chain of function calls (for example, SoC's GPIO module interrupt handler is being called from GIC interrupt handler, just as a function call)
   - `generic_handle_irq()` is used for interrupts chaining
   - child IRQ handlers are being called inside of parent HW IRQ handler
   - you can't call functions that may sleep in chained (child) interrupt handlers, because they are still in *atomic context* (HW interrupt)
   - this approach is commonly used in drivers for SoC's internal GPIO modules
2. Nested interrupts

   - "nested" means that those interrupts can be interrupted by another interrupt; but they are not really HW IRQs, but rather threaded IRQs
   - `handle_nested_irq()` is used for creating nested interrupts
   - child IRQ handlers are being called inside of new **thread** created by `handle_nested_irq()` function; we need them to be run in *process context*, so that we can call sleeping bus functions (like I2C functions that may sleep)
   - you are able to call functions that may sleep inside of nested (child) interrupt handlers
   - this approach is commonly used in drivers for external chips, like GPIO expanders, because they are usually connected to SoC via I2C bus, and I2C functions may sleep

Speaking of drivers discussed above:

- `irq-gic` driver uses `CHAINED GPIO irqchips` approach for handling systems with multiple GICs; [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b3a1bde4db9889feb116330bff21214811c940e4) commit adds that functionality
- `gpio-omap` driver (mentioned above) uses `GENERIC CHAINED GPIO irqchips` approach. See [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=450fa54cfd66e3dda6eda26256637ee8928af12a) commit. It was converted from using regular `CHAINED GPIO irqchips` so that on real-time kernel it will threaded IRQ handler, but on non-RT kernel it will be hard IRQ handler
- 'gpio-max732x' driver uses `NESTED THREADED GPIO irqchips` approach

> what does `chained_irq_enter` and `chained_irq_exit` do

Those functions implement hardware interrupt flow control, i.e. notifying interrupt controller chip when to mask and unmask current interrupt.

1. For [FastEOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_interrupt) interrupt controllers (most modern way):

   - `chained_irq_enter()` do nothing
   - `chained_irq_exit()` calls `irq_eoi()` callback to tell the interrupt controller that interrupt processing is finished
2. For interrupt controllers with mask/unmask/ack capabilities

   - `chained_irq_enter()` masks current interrupt, and acknowledges it if ack callback is set as well
   - `chained_irq_exit()` unmasks interrupt

> because after an interrupt is arised the irq line is disabled, but `chained_irq_enter` is calling functions related to masking interrupts if the line is already disabled why to mask the interrupt ?

IRQ line is disabled. But we still need to write to EOI register in the end of interrupt processing. Or send ACK for edge-level interrupts.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391340/when-we-use-irq-set-chained-handler-the-irq-line-will-be-disabled-or-not/34426034#34426034) explains why interrupts are disabled in interrupt handler.

Answer (score 2):

Read Linux kernel documentation itself for understanding these APIs:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/driver.txt

> - CHAINED GPIO irqchips: these are usually the type that is embedded on
>       an SoC. This means that there is a fast IRQ handler for the GPIOs that
>       gets called in a chain from the parent IRQ handler, most typically the
>       system interrupt controller. This means the GPIO irqchip is registered
>       using irq_set_chained_handler() or the corresponding
>       gpiochip_set_chained_irqchip() helper function, and the GPIO irqchip
>       handler will be called immediately from the parent irqchip, while
>       holding the IRQs disabled. The GPIO irqchip will then end up calling
>       something like this sequence in its interrupt handler:
>
>   ```
>   static irqreturn_t tc3589x_gpio_irq(int irq, void *data)
>       chained_irq_enter(...);
>       generic_handle_irq(...);
>       chained_irq_exit(...);
>   ```