# Getting information from the device tree and requesting irq

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, platform, device-tree

### Context

In the device tree I am using, in one of its node, the filed `interrupts` is:

```
interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>;
```

(from a device tree of a Pynq board, equipaged with a ZYnq device with a dual-core ARM A9 )

Now, in the device tree `.probe` function, I use the Linux kernel API:

```
irq_line = platform_get_irq(pdev, 0);
```

in order to get the irq to use for the function `request_irq` (described in [ldd3](https://bootlin.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf) chapter 10).

Ones the `irq_line = platform_get_irq(pdev, 0);` is executed, I get the value `0x2e` that DOESN'T match with the fields of the `interrupts` of the device tree.

### Questions

1. What are exactly the `<0x0 0x1d 0x4>` numbers? I know that, in according to [elinux.org](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage),:

> interrupts - A property of a device node containing a list of interrupt specifiers, one for each interrupt output signal on the device.

2. How can I get the *irq line* to use (maybe starting from these numbers)? Is the *irq line* related to the device tree?
3. Why am I getting a value that doesn't match with no one of the fields of `interrupts`?

I am sure I am misunderstanding some important topics, I am sorry. And thank you for reading the question and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are exactly the <0x0 0x1d 0x4> numbers? I know that, in according
>   to elinux.org, (interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>;)

Firstly you need to look at the interrupt-parent of the device node, this parent will #interrupt-cells property which [specifies number of bits needed to encode a interrupt source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/arm,gic.txt), so from your entry interrupts = <0x0 0x1d 0x4>; means the following:

```
0x0  = shared processor interrupts
0x1d = interrupt number
0x4  = active high level-sensitive/[IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH][2]
```

> How can I get the irq line to use (maybe starting from these numbers)?
>   Is the irq line related to the device tree?
>
> Why am I getting a value that doesn't match with no one of the fields
>   of interrupts?

Its well answered [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt) also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371352/what-are-linux-irq-domains-why-are-they-needed).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you have an idea why I am getting 0x2e instead of 0x1d?

Comment: That is because platform_get_irq() returns Linux  IRQ numbers, and not the actual hardware number.   A mapping is needed when you have two interrupt controllers, i.e. two irq_chip , are available (e.g. GIC and GPIO IC). To solve this problem, the Linux kernel came up with the notion of an IRQ domain which is a well-defined translation interface between hardware IRQ numbers and the one used internally in the kernel. GIC driver therefore creates its IRQ domain and its translation on init.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt

Comment: Add it on the answer!! I will have a look on it this weekend